# How to access host port after running docker compose up

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gunicorn

I am dockerizing a React-Flask web application with separate containers for the frontend and the backend Flask API. Up to now I have only run this on my localhost using the default Flask development server. I then installed Gunicorn to prep the application for deployment with Docker later, and that also ran smoothly on my localhost.

After I ran  `docker compose up` the two images built successfully, are attached to the same network, and I got this in the logs:

**Logs For backend:**

```
Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
Using worker: gthread
```

**Logs For frontend:**

```
react-flask-app@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start
Project is running at http://172.21.0.2/
Starting the development server...
```

But when I try to access the site at `http://172.21.0.2/`, localhost:5000 or localhost:3000 it is not accessible. Do I maybe need to add the name of the frontend or backend service?

In Docker Desktop it's showing that the frontend is running at port 5000 but there is no port listed for the backend, it just says it's running.

This is what my files and setup look like:

I added a `gunicorn_config.py` file as I read it is a good practice, rather than adding all of the arguments to the CMD in the Dockerfile:

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:5000"
workers = 4
threads = 4
timeout = 120
```

Then in my **Flask backend Dockerfile** I have the following CMD for Gunicorn:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
ADD . /app
COPY . .
RUN apk add build-base
RUN apk add libffi-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn_config.py", "main:app"]
```

Here I do `"main:app"` where my Flask app file is called `main.py`and then `app` is my Flask app object.

I'm generally confused about ports and how this will interact with Gunicorn and in general. I specified port 5000 in the `EXPOSE` of both of my Dockerfiles.

**This is my frontend Dockerfile:**

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
COPY package*.json ./ 
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm" ]
CMD ["start"]
```

And used 5000 in the `bind` value of my `Gunicorn config` file. Also, I previously added port 5000 as a proxy in `package.json.`

I will initially want to run the application using Docker on my localhost but will deploy it to a public host service like Digital Ocean later.

**This is my Docker compose file:**

```
services:
  middleware:
   build: .
   ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  frontend:
    build: 
      context: ./react-flask-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

The other thing to mention is that I also created a ****wsgi.py**** file and I was wondering do I need to add this to the Gunicorn `CMD` in my Dockerfile:

```
from main import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried to open http://localhost:5000 instead ? (172.21.0.* addresses are usually not visible outside docker)

Comment: Yep, I tried that, and localhost:3000 which is what I previously used to get the app running locally. I edited my question to mention that as I really should have said that.

Comment: Regarding the backend : it's possible to have two different applications on your machine that use the same port. In the docker-compose up, you'll have to route ports. For example: "5000:5000" for the frontend and "5001:5000" for the backend. (left part is the port used on your local machine, right part is the port used by the service inside a docker machine)

Comment: I've changed frontend ports to 3000:3000 and building that now. If it doesn't work I'll try this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `telnet` from within the container as well, just to confirm.

Comment: @nlko, Nishant: it worked! thanks for your support.